# What is the way to include more than two selector and applying more than two properties in css under div tag

Tags: html, css

I have issue in css syntax .

```
 <div class="demo">
   <p>This is stackoverflow</p>
     <ul>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>sec</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Then how I should apply more than one css in each `p` and `ul` .

Comment: Add separate classes or ids to p and ul. Add appropriate css styles to those class or id.

Comment: Try to look at these articles by MDN
 
selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors . 

class selectors : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "more than one CSS"? What do you mean by "each `<p>`", since you have only one?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I'm really understanding your question..

**HTML**

```
 <div class="demo">
   <p>This is stackoverflow</p>
    <ul>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>sec</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

These would let your target the **p** and **ul** seperately, applying whatever rules you want to them.

**CSS**

```
div.demo p{
     color:red;
}
div.demo ul{
     color:blue;
}
```

---

If you wanted to add more classes, you could do something like this

**HTML**

```
 <div class="demo">
   <p class="paragraph">This is stackoverflow</p>
    <ul class="list">
        <li>first</li>
        <li>sec</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

These would let your target the **p** and **ul** at the same time, applying whatever rules you want to them.

**CSS**

```
.paragraph, .list {
     color:green ;
}
```

---

You could also combine the two, and rather than add new classes, just specify that you want to apply the rules to both.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="demo">
   <p>This is stackoverflow</p>
    <ul>
        <li>first</li>
        <li>sec</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

These would let your target the **p** and **ul** at the same time, applying whatever rules you want to them.

**CSS**

```
div.demo p, div.demo ul{
     color:purple;
}
```

---

There are tons of ways to do things; if you could add more detail to your question we'd be able to help you better.

Comment: If you feel like it, accept the answer I posted? @VikashKumar

Comment: My question was how to do css if there is already ul li in html program.So for if again the ul li and some other elements are present are present ,so what to do to make changes to specific list and paragraph here